# Drupal 8 online conferencing that integrates with CiviCRM?

Tags: drupal, civimember, evaluating-civicrm

Not precisely a CiviCRM question, but this is something that I suspect other people here have already faced and solved, and I'm hoping to get feedback.

I'm redoing our website for a nonprofit, with an expectation of using Drupal 8 or 9 integrated with CiviCRM. The primary feature I'm looking for in our migration is to integrate online conferencing and a collaborative work environment. (We've looked into using third-party sites for the latter; I'm still willing to run this separately, but most of the options out there have per-user costs, which is unsustainable for us.)

The closest things to what we want as Drupal distributions are Open Atrium (which appears to be deprecated and Drupal 7 only) and Open Social (which I haven't been able to get to play nice with CiviCRM, and has other restrictions I haven't been able to deal with in an unpaid site; paid options are too expensive).

How have other people approached this? Ideally, we want organizational management to be run within CiviCRM, with integration with the online discussion such that new members are automatically provisioned with various permissions, and we can use CiviCRM entities to drive how interactions work across the site. (E.g., if the collaborative site uses Groups, that this integrates with CiviCRM functionality.)

Answer (score 1):

We would approach this using Groups. We have used OG extensively and built additional integration in terms of what drives creation of Groups and Group membership in D7, and are in process of looking at replicating in D9 currently. For example:

Events

- creation of civi event triggers creation of Drupal Group
- registration of participent triggers adding user as member of above Group

Relationships (for example committee members)

- committee Contact in civi is linked to a corresponding Group in Drupal
- a relationship of type X to that committee adds the user to the above Group

and of course CiviCRM already had (not certain is working in D9 yet)

Groups

- a Group in civi is linked to a Group in Drupal
- a contact in that civi group is added as a member of the related Group in Drupal

In all above, removal (eg ending Relationship) triggers removal from the Drupal Group too